# Intersect with Raster data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, intersect

I have ArcGIS 10.2.2

I have raster data over a whole state but am looking at just analyzing a specific county. I downloaded county polygons to overlay over the raster data to determine the area I want to study.

I wish to extract the the county information from the whole dataset so I can just work and analyze the information I want.

I tried to use intersect but since I have polygon and raster data (different formats) I couldn't use the command.

Is there another command I could use to extract the data?

Comment: What program are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a program such as QGIS or ArcGIS there are several tools called something like "Clip Raster by Extent" or "clip grid with polygon". These will work to whittle down your original data set to one that is more in line with your AOI.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS you can use [Clip](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ArcGISDesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00170000009n000000) (Data Management toolbox).

Alternatively, you can also selected specific county polygon, [convert selected feature into graphics](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00s90000001v000000.htm) and export the raster (Data -> Export Data) using "Selected Graphics" extent option:

[image]